# PHPUnit assertDatabaseHas() returning TypeError

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Trying to test a model here, but every time that I try to use the assertDatabaseHas method it gives me the type error. Laravel 5.4 and PHPUnit 6.

```
    PHPUnit 6.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..E                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 815 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\ModelTest::test_model_creation
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertThat() must be an instance of PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Constraints\HasInDatabase given, called in /home/vagrant/domains-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.php on line 22

/home/vagrant/domains-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.php:22
/home/vagrant/domains-api/tests/Unit/ModelTest.php:36

ERRORS!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 2, Errors: 1.
```

Code inside the test class:

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('domains', [
            'domain' => $domain,
            'domain_type' => 'full_domain',
        ]);
```

I using the laravel docs as reference and the syntax seems to be correct (at least for me).
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#introduction

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Laravel 5.4 does not support the namespace for PHPUnit introduced with version 6.

If you compare the branches it is easy to see:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Constraints/HasInDatabase.php#L8

vs.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Constraints/HasInDatabase.php#L6-L8

I think the best solution is to either run the tests with PHPUnit 5.x or possibly update `laravel/framework` to use master. Since the master might contain breaking changes the first seems to be the safer approach for now.

Comment: Working fine now... Change my composer.lock to stick with the PHPunit 5.7.* (it was ~5.7 before) and after run the composer update the assertDatabaseHas method is working as it should be now.