# laravel assertDatabaseHas() testing method doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and PHPUnit 6.5.5. I keep getting the following error when using Laravel's `assertDatabaseHas()` method in my tests.

```
Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertDatabaseHas()
```

This is my code fragment using `assertDatabaseHas()`:

```
$response = $this->withSession(['user_id' => $this->user_id])
    ->json('post',
        route('some_route'),
        $request //an array 
    );

    $request['myuser_id'] = $this->user_id;

    $response->assertStatus($expected['code'])
        ->assertDatabaseHas('profiles',$request);
```

I also tried to use `$this->assertDatabaseHas()`, but a new error appeared:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertThat() must be an instance of PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Constraints\HasInDatabase given, called in /project_path/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.php on line 22
```

I searched for a while for the problem's solution and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251941/phpunit-assertdatabasehas-returning-typeerror) , but downgrading PHPUnit version to 5.* didn't work for me.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($request);`?

Comment: $request is just an associative array ['id' => 2 , 'name' => 'test' , ....] @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: What's your exact Laravel version?

Comment: 5.4.36 @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: Do you get the same error with PHPUnit 5.*?

Comment: Yes.No change with older PHPUnit version!

Comment: Using `$this->assertDatabaseHas()` (`$response->assertDatabaseHas()` won't work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my laravel version from 5.4.37 to 5.5.40 and problem solved.
assertDatabaseHas() works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

`assertDatabaseHas()` always worked, you were just using it incorrectly and a change in Laravel versions would not have fixed your problem.

You're dealing with two separate entities here – an HTTP response and a database entry – and they need to be treated as such. The return from a method such as `json()` or `assertStatus()` is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Response` and has no database methods.

Keep these things separate: make the HTTP request and check the response, then check the database.

```
$this
    ->withSession(['user_id' => $this->user_id])
    ->json('post', route('some_route'), $request)
    ->assertStatus($expected['code']);

$request['myuser_id'] = $this->user_id;

$this->assertDatabaseHas('profiles', $request);
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer and should be accepted as the accepted one. Original post please review and change.